# Screen.height not working correctly in firefox while zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant able to get the default screen.height value in the firefox while i am zoom the browsers.

While i am zoom the browsers in chrome and IE the screen.height is remain unchanged but in firefox it is changing continuously.

please provide me some helpful solutions.

Thanks in advance